# Clean up translation output after xml file translation

Tags: xml, python-3.x, translation, docx

I need to translate some WORD files (.docx) and I'm doing so by extracting the 'document.xml' file and translating it with YandexTranslate.

My code :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Et
from yandex_translate import YandexTranslate
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('myfrenchfile.docx') as zf:
    zf.extract(r'word/document.xml')

with open('word/document.xml', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    tree = Et.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot()

    for elem in root.getiterator():
        translate = YandexTranslate(
            'myyandexkey')
        try:
            if elem.text:
                elem.text = elem.text.replace(elem.text, str(translate.translate(elem.text, 'en')))
        except AttributeError:
            pass

tree.write('document.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

This works but since I'm forced to pass 'str' on 'translate.translate()' for the translation to work I get an output populated with «{'lang': 'fr-en', 'code': 200, 'text': ['» and similar. I've tried the replace method as in

```
str(translate.translate(elem.text, 'en')).\
                    replace('{\'lang\': \'fr-en\', \'code\': 200, \'text\': [\'', '').\
                    replace('\']}', '').replace('{\'lang\': \'en-en\', \'code\': 200, \'text\': [\'', '').\
                    replace('{\'lang\': \'en-en\', \'text\': [\'', '').\
                    replace('\'], \'code\': 200}', '').replace('{\'code\': 200, \'lang\': \'en-en\', \'text\': [\'', '')\
                    .replace('{\'code\': 200, \'lang\': \'fr-en\', \'text\': [\'', '').\
                    replace('{\'code\': 200, \'lang\': \'de-en\', \'text\': [\'', '').\
                    replace('{\'lang\': \'de-en\', \'code\': 200, \'text\': [\'', '')
```

If I print the output, it's clean, but when the file is written it's not.

Does someone have a solution to write the translation text only to the new xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Made it work by adding 'str' to 'elem.text':

```
try:
        if elem.text:
            elem.text = elem.text.replace(str(elem.text), str(translate.translate(elem.text, 'en')).
                                          replace('{\'lang\': \'fr-en\', \'code\': 200, \'text\': [\'', '').
                                          replace('\']}', '').replace('{\'lang\': \'en-en\', \'code\': 200, '
                                                                      '\'text\': [\'', '').
                                          replace('{\'lang\': \'en-en\', \'text\': [\'', '').
                                          replace('\'], \'code\': 200}', '').
                                          replace('{\'code\': 200, \'lang\': \'en-en\', \'text\': [\'', '').
                                          replace('{\'code\': 200, \'lang\': \'fr-en\', \'text\': [\'', '').
                                          replace('{\'code\': 200, \'lang\': \'de-en\', \'text\': [\'', '').
                                          replace('{\'lang\': \'de-en\', \'code\': 200, \'text\': [\'', '').
                                          replace('{\'lang\': \'pl-en\', \'code\': 200, \'text\': [\'', ''))
```

Not really sure why...